# SQL get count of one column values and group by another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I have 3 columns like so:

```
NAME ZONE_ID GROUP_ID
Mark 11       1
Mary 11       1
Mart 12       1
Mike 11       2
Kent 13       2
```

Now I want to count all the zone_id-s for a specific group. So the output for group 1 would be that there are 2 entries in zone 11 and 1 entry in zone 12 and for group 2 that there is 1 entry for zone 11 and one entry in zone 13.

It doesn't seem like it would be a very difficult query but I have hard time searching for it the right way and haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group by group_id, zone_id`:

```
select group_id, zone_id, count(*) counter
from tablename
group by group_id, zone_id
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. I did not know you could group by 2 different columns.